# Why does Aquamacs freeze?

Tags: applications

Aquamacs freezes upon re-start. If I delete `.emacs.d/SessionDesktop.el` before restarting, all works fine.

What is the issue there? How can I avoid this (save for deleting SessionDesktop.el everytime).

Thanks.

Comment: What is in session desktop.el?

Comment: Are you quitting the app cleanly?  If you are, it's potentially a bug.  Submit a report:  http://aquamacs.org/reporting-bugs.shtml